# Sum of particular column of all tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have multiple tables, for instance January, February and so on. And every month has a column of 'Profit'. I can find the total profit of each month easily by:

```
select sum(profit) from January
```

But let's say I want a table/view that automatically calculates the total Profit of each month. Is there a way that calculates that for me of all the tables in that particular database?

Also, if I update any row, then it automatically updates the view/table. That can be done easily.

Any hints? Obviously, the join clause with sum of each month won't help.

Comment: If you are able to change the design, I'd recommend having a *single* table with a `Month` column. Data that has the same structure and meaning should be in the same table.

Comment: yes. Definately bad design. These should be all in a single table with year & month as part of the primary key

Comment: Yeah that would be a great idea. And then I can look at the monthly cost by using the GROUP clause

Answer (score 1):

If you want the total profit of each month, then you can create a `view` to use `union all` to get the results.

```
select *
from (
   select sum(profit) profit, 'January' mnth from January
   union all
   select sum(profit) profit, 'February' mnth from February
   union all
   select sum(profit) profit, 'March' mnth from March
   ...
   select sum(profit) profit, 'December' mnth from December
) t
```

One thing to consider, storing monthly data in separate tables might not be the best idea.  In general this can be altered to a more normalized approach.